# How to fix wrong imported datetime in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I did an import from a CSV file into the database and didnt recognize that the date was formated wrong so I ended up with dates like this:

```
2027-05-14 00:00:00
```

instead of this

```
2014-05-27 00:00:00
```

I found this query but its not really what I am looking for. As im just able to maniuplate the Year but what I need actually is extracting the last 2 position of the year and set this as the day. The year is always 2014 and the month can stay as it is.

```
UPDATE table_name SET date_col=DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'2014-%m-%d %T');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name SET date_col=DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'2014-%m-%y %T');
```

`%y` is the year in 2 digits.

A slightly more reliable way is

```
UPDATE table_name SET date_col=DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'20%d-%m-%y %T');
```

to put the day in the years place and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use this part of your code

```
 date_col=DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'2014-%m-%d %T');
```

if you want to get the value of date_col, select it first via subquery. Look at my example

```
 UPDATE table_name SET date_col=DATE_FORMAT((select date_col from table_name where _____),'2014-%m-%d %T');
```